# TypeORM relation returns object with null parameters when relation ID column is null

Tags: typeorm

I'm using Repository API with Typeorm

I have an entity, called ApprovalRegistry, that has a relation with a User entity defined this way:

```js
...
  @Column({ name: 'approver_user_id', type: 'int' })
  approverUserId: number | null;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.id)
  @JoinColumn({
    name: 'approver_user_id',
    referencedColumnName: 'id',
  })
  approverUser: User | null;
...
```

Then, when I call the `find` method to this repository, I always want to get the approverUser relation, so it's done this way:

```js
  public async findRequestApprovalRegistry(
    requestId: number,
    { approvalLevelId, approvalStatusId }: FindRequestApprovalRegistryQueryDto,
    userId?: number,
  ) {
    return this.registryRepo.find({
      where: {
        requestId,
        approvalLevelId,
        approvalStatusId,
      },
      relations: {
        approvalLevel: true,
        approverUser: true,
        approvalStatus: true,
      },
      order: {
        approvalLevel: {
          level: 'asc',
        },
      },
    });
  }
```

Here, I'm telling to retrieve the record, with the approverUser relation just by setting `approvalUser: true`.

So the expected behaviour would be that the actual returned object for approverUser would be null if approverUserId is null or the returned object for approverUser would be an User object.

But actually what I'm getting if approverUserId is null, it's an object with all properties set to null.

```json
"approverUser": {
  "id": null,
  "username": null,
  "email": null,
  "displayName": null,
  "firstName": null,
  "lastName": null,
  "disabled": null,
  "deleted": false
}
```

Actually it's the first time I realize this is happening and I don't know if that's the expected behaviour, but it makes no sense.

Can someone tell me if that's the case or have I maybe missed something?

---

**EDIT**:

I've solved the question, obtaining the desired result just by adding the option `relationLoadStrategy: 'query'` to the find method.

The definition I see for this option is:

> Specifies how relations must be loaded - using "joins" or separate queries. If you are loading too much data with nested joins it's better to load relations using separate queries.
> Default strategy is "join", but default can be customized in connection options.

I suppose I'd usually use the query strategy anytime there's a posibility that the relation is null.

Comment: This happens when the main entity is using a @VirtualColumn decorator.